# How to use a colorbrewer scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following:

```
<script src="http://colorbrewer2.org/export/colorbrewer.js"></script>
...
...
var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
        .range(colorbrewer.YlGnBu[9]);
...
...
colorScale.domain([0,layers.length]);
console.log(layers.length)   //<<< this returns 8
```

The whole chart is coming through as black - why are the colorbrewer colors not being used?

---

update

Here is a full working (black!) example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/JqL0rYIjhZz9gf6102j7?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is changing `http` to `https` in your reference, or changing the reference itself (I'm getting a "connection timed out" with your src):

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/colorbrewer.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Other than that, a Brewer scale is just an array, and it's used as you use an array in any other D3 scale.

Here is a working demo. First, we set the scale:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
    .range(colorbrewer.YlGnBu[9])
    .domain([0,9]);
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
    .range(["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb",
            "#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"])
    .domain([0,9]);
```

And then we use it to color the circles:

```
.attr("fill", function(d){ return colorScale(d)});
```

Check the demo:

```js
var dataset = d3.range(9);
var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
    .range(colorbrewer.YlGnBu[9])
    .domain([0, 9]);

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg");

var circles = svg.selectAll(".circles")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("circle");

circles.attr("cy", 50)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return 50 + d * 20
    })
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return colorScale(d)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/colorbrewer.v1.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:** Your bars in the plunkr are black for a reason. You're defining the `colorScale` as a quantize:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
    .range(colorbrewer.YlGnBu[9])
    .domain([0, 8]);
```

But then, later, you're setting it a qualitative domain!

```
  colorScale.domain(layers.map(function(layer) {
       return layer.key;
  }));
```

This will simply not work! According to the API (emphases mine):

> Quantize scales are a variant of **linear** scales with a discrete rather than continuous range. The input domain is **still continuous**, and divided into uniform segments based on the number of values in (the cardinality of) the output range.

Thus, you'll have to decide what you want. This is a plunkr with the ordinal scale: https://plnkr.co/edit/qYi0y4A49UIDawZBr5kF?p=preview

Comment: again your help is invaluable Gerardo. This learning curve is quite extensive for me as I'm coming from a background that does not include *any* web dev: I initially estimated 3 months to get up to speed but I suspect 6 months is more realistic as I'm seeing the creation of pie charts - or charts including curves as a further 'level-up' and then map visualizations as a further 'level-up' involving additional skills.

Comment: let me add a full working example to my original question - as it is still black!

Comment: (In this sort of case I should be able to up by 2 ! ... thanks for the extra information)

Comment: Hi Gerardo - you said "I'm getting a "connection timed out" with your src" ... so I can check this myself in the future - where do I find this information in firebug ? In the console?